# flex input box doesnot work in fullscreen mode

Tags: flash, apache-flex, internet-explorer, flex4, fullscreen

i have a problem in flex fullscreen mode... 
that is my input box doesnot work in fullscreen mode.
I could'nt able to type anything. and no keydown events are working.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately keyboard control in full screen is very limited.

From Adobe documentation:

> Currently, Adobe Flash Player does not allow keyboard input when
>   displaying content in full-screen mode. Flash Player 10 changes this,
>   allowing for a limited number of keys to be usable in full-screen
>   mode. These include Tab, the Space bar, and the (up, down, left,
>   right) arrow keys.
>
> This change affects all SWF files played in Flash Player 10 or later.
>   This includes SWF files published for earlier versions of Flash, so
>   long as they are played within Flash Player 10. This also affects
>   non-app content in AIR.
>
> Note: App content in AIR can set the value of stage.displayState to
>   StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE for full keyboard support in
>   full-screen mode.

Original article [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/405/kb405548.html).

For more details check [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS2E9C7F3B-6A7C-4c5d-8ADD-5B23446FBEEB.html).